# What is the trigger error function in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it okay to use the trigger_error function when the site is live?

Example below.

```
// Make the connection:
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if (!$dbc) {
    trigger_error ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are not displaying errors on screen (`display_errors = Off`) in php.ini, it is wise to use `trigger_error()` in your script. It will cause an error message to be written to the error log.

I will add that it is generally not good practice to use the `@` for error suppression.  Problems with `mysqli_connect()` will be written to the error log as well, if you leave off the `@`.

Comment: Wouldn't you say a try-catch is more appropriate for this type of error?

Comment: PHP errors aren't exceptions -- they're something separate. It's a bit of a wart in the language.